ULN2003A connections
I'm using an Arduino Nano ESP32 to manage three relays.
Can I use the ULN2003A component in that way?
Or do I need to place something else?


It looks perfect to me. There's no more to say.

The circuit looks fine as long as the connections between the relays and the ULN2003 are short. That's because you're using the flyback diodes inside of ULN2003. Those diodes need to be close to the relays.
The COM pin of the ULN2003 should be a "star" power distribution point for the relays. That ensures that the flyback currents flow in a dedicated loop that won't affect other circuitry, and will keep the EMI to a minimum.
There should be a bulk capacitor connected between the COM and E pins of the ULN2003. The power traces should connect to that capacitor, not directly to the ULN2003. That should keep the AC currents shunted by the capacitor, and they won't flow to the rest of the circuit.
The 100nF capacitor is a bit "optimistic". It can be left in, but there should be a bulk capacitor actually attached between COM and E. And that capacitor should be graphically shown to be so connected. The detached style with net names misses the point of what schematics are: graphical means of conveying technical idea, not graphical means of representing a netlist.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It is possible to draw the star connection nicer using KiCad - the lines should be angled and connect to a common point. That will express well to an observant reader (now it's you :) how the layout should be done. Similarly, C1 can show star points to indicate that it is the attach point to power.

An even more direct way to convey the idea that the relays are to be connected through dedicated traces directly to points on the ULN2003A would be:

There's nothing that forces anyone to keep all the lines on a schematic to only two directions - horizontal or vertical. Nothing besides default preferences in most circuit editors.
Of course, wires going at all angles in a rats nest would not be acceptable. But here we are expressing a design intent that should be reproduced in the layout, and should also inform anyone reading the schematic who wants to understand what decisions were made in the design as a whole.

what happens if the diodes are not close? and why?

Thank you for your answer!

I'm interested to know also if the micro controller suffer any flyback behaviour by the coils. There is the need to add any optocoupler in the middle? Or something similar to decouple the ULN2003A and the Arduino?
I saw from Kincony schematics (https://www.kincony.com/download/KC868-A6-schematic.pdf) that is used a 74HCT14. For what is that component for? I see that it inverts the input, but does it also isolate somehow?

-optocouplers can fix grounding problems in poorly built circuits, but that's 50c worth of silicon replacing 5c worth of copper.

Looks fine. You can use a zener diode between the COM terminal and +12 to get a bit more contact life (closer to the datasheet specifications) at the expense of a bit more EMI. Something like 12V.
As other answers indicate- pay attention to the relay coil current flow and especially the flow of noise coupled back through the relay coil-contact capacitance.
